# How can I display 4 TDs in my table then create a new table row using PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop, html-table, row

I am running a for loop grabbing data from a database and I want to create a new row every time I create 4 table datas, how could I go by doing this?

example:

```
<table>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add a counter in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use Modular arithmetic: http://snook.ca/archives/php/the_modulo_oper

(not my site, I googled it for this gentleman.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do the trick.

```
$i = 0;
echo "<table><tr>";
while ($i < 50) {
  echo "<td></td>";
  if ($i % 4 == 0) {
    echo "</tr><tr>";
  }
  $i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

I let you handle as a homework the case where you end width a `$i%4 == 0` so you end the code with `</tr><tr></tr></table>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>

<?php

$i = 0;

foreach ($data as $item)
{

  echo "<td>$item</td>";

  $i++;

  if ($i % 4 == 0)
  {
    echo "</tr>\n<tr>";
  }
}

// if total count of $data is not divisible with 4,
// we have to complete the last row with empty cells
for ($j = 0; $j < (4 - ($i % 4)); $j++)
{
  echo "<td> </td>";
}

?>
  </tr>

</table>
```